# Sending any Android build shows build error server response code 401

Tags: codenameone

I see an error server returned http response code 401 whenever I try to send Android build for any project. I have even tried to send an unchanged version of the KitchenSink demo. I'm assuming I am missing an update of some kind. Below is the message on the output console:

```
You sent an android build without submitting a keystore. Notice that you will receive a build that is inappropriate for distribution (although it could be used for debugging purposes). For further details read http://www.codenameone.com/signing.html
Your build size is: 680kb
Sending build request to the server, notice that the build might take a while to complete!
Sending build to account: my@email.com
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://cloud.codenameone.com/appsec/7.0/build/upload
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1876)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.access$200(HttpURLConnection.java:91)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1466)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$9.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1464)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivilegedWithCombiner(AccessController.java:782)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1463)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.sendS3Build(BuildProcess.java:469)
    at com.codename1.build.client.BuildProcess.sendRequestToServer(BuildProcess.java:500)
    at com.codename1.build.client.CodeNameOneBuildTask.execute(CodeNameOneBuildTask.java:529)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor83.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1405)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1376)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
C:\Users\jn\Documents\NetBeansProjects\KitchenSink\build.xml:343: Error in server build process
BUILD FAILED (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Make sure your Open Codename One settings, run an update and restart settings. Then do a logout. Then try sending the build again

Comment: Hi, thank you for the advice. Unfortunately following your advice I still see the same error.

Comment: Are you sure the libs are up to date?
Open regedit and look for codename1 and codenameone. Delete all the registry entries you find.

Comment: Deleting the entries in the registry has resolved the issue. Many thanks Shai